# Array count in php

Tags: php

Hello everyone i want to count total number of record in array.I tried with following code but not worked. i want "2" as result for current array. Here is my code and current array value showing.

```
print_r(array_count_values($participants));

Array
(
    [0] => abc
        (
            [version:protected] => Twilio\Rest\Api\V2010 Object
                (
                )
        )
    [1] => abc
        (
            [version:protected] => Twilio\Rest\Api\V2010 Object
                (
                )
        )
)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find the size of Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42226780/how-to-find-the-size-of-array)

Comment: http://php.net/count, if you're struggling to count arrays, read that manual, from front to back

Comment: use : `count($array)`

Comment: Try this `count(array_count_values($participants));`

Answer (score 0):

```
echo sizeof($participants);
```

or

```
echo count($participants);
```

Comment: Krauti : i am getting error " array_count_values() expects parameter 1 to be array, object given in "

Answer (score 0):

```
$participants = Array
(
    [0] => abc
        (
            [version:protected] => Twilio\Rest\Api\V2010 Object
                (
                )
        )
    [1] => abc
        (
            [version:protected] => Twilio\Rest\Api\V2010 Object
                (
                )
        )
)

print_r(count($participants));
```

Comment: i getting error " array_count_values() expects parameter 1 to be array, object given in "