# How get tags length from Youtube API using PHP

Tags: php, youtube-api

I tried to get tags length from `Youtube API` but the result nothing

*Tags preview*

[image]

*PHP*

```
$tags = $vid["items"][0]["snippet"]["tags"];
echo $tags.length;
```

*Browser Result*

> Warning: Use of undefined constant length - assumed 'length' (this
>   will throw an Error in a future version of PHP)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find the size of Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42226780/how-to-find-the-size-of-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confusing javascript and PHP.

```
echo $tags.length; // incorrect
```

This is how:

```
echo count($tags);
```